# How can I store massive amounts of text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, text

I want to store massive amounts of data, specifically the amount of text equivalent to a book. How can I go about this? Is there a type of data storage that makes this process faster/easier (aka is fit) for this type of operation?

Comment: hat depends a lot on what you want to do with the data. What will your queries look like?

Comment: Basically people will have a textarea input, and all that text will be dumped into the database.

Comment: The relevant part is not the interface for entering data, but what you want to do with the data once you have stored them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html), but not that much. A single database can have (with default configurations) over a billion tables and each table can be 32TB in size.